# Running vim autocommands only on recognized filetypes

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to run `autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * update` only for files 'understood' by vim filetypes instead of `*`. For instance, I don't want to run it for an unsaved buffer. I understand that the expression can be guarded by an `if` but I can't figure out how to write this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want to achieve, expressed in the simplest terms:

> I want something to happen only on recognised filetypes

which you can then express with some pseudocode:

```
if Vim assigned a filetype to this buffer
    do something
endif
```

Now, what better way to know if the current buffer has a `filetype` than ask Vim?

```
if &filetype != ""
    update
endif
```

which is not pseudocode anymore and only needs to be inlined:

```
if &filetype != "" | update | endif
```

to be used in your autocommand:

```
augroup MyAutoSave
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorHold,CursorHoldI * if &filetype != "" | update | endif
augroup END
```

Comment: Great explanation. The `autogroup` works well too, thanks.